# How to reset location warnings in ios from javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, location

Is it possible to reset the location warnings in ios from javascript run on the website?

I am finding that if users keep denying access to their location when visiting my website that eventually they no longer get the choice. Now I know that they can reset their settings on their iPhones but I would like to be able to force the "Deny or Allow" dialog box to appear every time they visit my website.

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: If they have been denying access all along, why would they change their mind? Even if they did, why not instruct them on how to re-enable it?

Comment: The website works perfectly well if people deny access to their location. It is expected that users will deny access sometimes and allow access at other times. That is why I always want them to have the choice. Telling them to reset their location privacy settings is not ideal.

Comment: Maybe wait for a user interaction (like pressing a button) before asking for permission? Then users only have to allow it when they want to use it.

Comment: Yes they do indeed have to press a Go button before the javascript to get their location is run.